# How to re-order windows, change the scroll shortcut, and modify the status bar contents in GNU Screen?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I learned to use gnu-screen and have been using it for the past several weeks. I got a grip of the basics now, and would be very helpful if I get these queries clarified:

1. How do I rename / reorder / move windows in Linux screen utility?

   For eg., after a few days of use, I come to a state where the window-numbers are 2, 3, 6, 8. Now I want a new-window to be created at #9, or #7. Is this possible? If yes, how?

   Also, is it possible to 'move' the window #6 to #4 or #7? If yes, how?
2. Scrolling shortcut: Scroll takes Ctrl-A + Esc, and then Ctrl-u / Ctrl-d. Is there a way to map PgUp / PgDn to do these directly? Or, is there a way to map some key (like F5) to take me to copy mode, and then PgUp / PgDn for scrolling?
3. I have enabled "caption always", so the current window title is displayed always at the bottom. Is there a way to display the current window's log-file-name and logging status (on/off) in the same caption bar?

Comment: `:number X` moves window to specific position

Comment: Check this out `hardstatus string "%{.kG}%-Lw%{.KW}%n%f %t%{-}%+Lw %=%{..G} %H %{..W} %d/%m %C%a "` it provides a lot of information (Z$L..) for all windows at time

Comment: Ency : thanks for the hardstatus string tip. It shows lot of details, but not the logfile name and status info. Any idea on this ?

Comment: I would highly suggest you try [tmux](https://tmux.github.io/) instead. It has many more features than screen and is much better at managing windows. For example you can do a vertical split whereas with screen you can only do a horizontal split.

Comment: You may want to look at the source for Byobu. Byobu is a very nice configuration package for Screen which takes a lot of advantage of the bottom bar: https://launchpad.net/byobu Bostonvaulter's suggestion of tmux is good too if that's available to you. If you have to log on to a lot of systems you don't necessarily have a lot of control over, it's good to know Screen since it's more widely available.

Comment: That's not true, in screen do ctrl+A ctrl+| for a vertical split

Comment: @NickGarvey the vertical split patch for screen is not in GNU Screen. It is a patch that is applied by some distros.

Comment: moved to github: https://tmux.github.io/

Answer (score 152):

You can renumber the current window with `ctrl+a` `:number x` where x is a numeric argument.

You can rename the current window with `ctrl+a` `A`

Comment: Renumbering even works if the new number is already in use. In this case the windows exchange their numbers. Nice.

Comment: I was a little confused at first. You have to type the literal string "number" and x is the kind of parameter to the number renaming function.

Comment: More symetrically and easier to remember you can do: `ctrl+a` `:title new window title`

Comment: @WadihM. just so long as there's no spaces in the new_window_title

Answer (score 48):

You can move windows up and down with this:

`ctrl+a` `:windowlist`  then   `. (dot)`-down and `, (comma)`-up

or

`ctrl+a "` then   `. (dot)`-down and `, (comma)`-up

(From [here](https://superuser.com/a/197206/143851).)

Comment: Adding to weinerk's answer, you can show list of windows by `ctrl+a "`

Comment: :windowlist is way more useful than :number when doing a big cleanup / reorganisation.

Comment: Another somewhat relevant feature for ease of navigation - 
you can name/rename each window:


`ctrl+a A`


or


`ctrl+a :title`